# I'm trying to learn python and my code doesn't work and i don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x

whats my mistake?
it doesn't show *you are right*

```
print("what's the correct number?")
print("1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9")
correctNumber = 6
inputNumber = input()
if inputNumber == correctNumber:
    print("you are right")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
correctNumber = 6
inputNumber = int(input("what's the correct number? 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9"))
if inputNumber == correctNumber:
    print("you are right")
```

The problem was that input is store in a variable as a string and you need to cast it to `int` to compare it with `int` since `correctNumber = 6` is `int`.
By the way, the `input` method expects a string to print the user before his input so you don't need to use print statements to notify the user about the expected input.

Answer (score 0):

When using input(), you get a string that you compare int () and str (). to get a number in water you need int(input())